# Prevent ac-etags from updating tags

Tags: emacs, tags

I'd like to know how to prevent ac-etags from updating tags which makes Emacs blocked/hung while it is doing updates.
Or it would be more nice if you have an idea to let Emacs do it asynchronously.

Please leave your ideas to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: This is too broad. Did you do any research? What have you tried? Show some programming context please.

Comment: Hi Maciej, I'm totally a newbiew to Emacs. Could you give me some hitns or tips, please?

Comment: Hello. I'm just reviewing the quality of your question so that people will be more likely to help you. Please make sure you do some effort to solve the problem and ask a specific question. Here you have some guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Maciej. I will keep that in mind. Anyhow I decided to leave it as it doesn't take so long time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `company-mode` (http://company-mode.github.io/) instead which won't update tags file at all. Besides `company-mode` is actively maintained.

If you still want to auto-update tags file in some way, try `counsel-etags` (https://github.com/redguardtoo/counsel-etags) which provides complete and fast solution to update tags file and code navigation